# Dismiss dialog box within asynctask

Tags: android

So I want to dismiss my dialog box after I have completed my asynctask but eclipse tells me that it cannot be resolved. So I try to move it outside of the onCreate() activity so that the asynctask can see it, but the app forcecloses when it is ran. When I look at DDMS it tells me that "System services not available to activites before oncreate".

Can someone help me out here. Thank you in advance.

```
    private class createUser extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    int va = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
            "Creating User...", true);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (db.createUser(nameU.getText().toString(), userU.getText()
                .toString(), emailU.getText().toString(), passU.getText()
                .toString()) == false) {
            va = 0;
        } else {
            va = 1;
        }



        return va;
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Integer result) {
        dialog.dismiss();
        if (result == 0) {
            toast.setText("User already exists!");
            toast.show();

            va = 0;

        } else {
            toast.setText("Success");
            toast.show();
            createU.dismiss(); //cannot be resolve
            va = 1;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your activity code and the exception that you are seeing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized after countless hours of looking through the code I had found a way to retieve the result from the 'AsyncTask' and test to make sure it was true or false.